# Can I use the promotional Apple images in my apps tutorial screen?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, development

Hey I am using the stock apple iPhone images to place my screenshots over: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#images. My app has a tutorial screen in it where you can swipe between screens and get instructions on how to use the app. I would also like to use these images for the tutorial. Is this allowed? I noticed there are two points on the page:

**2.2 Image use
The Apple product images of iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch can be used only to promote your app available on the App Store. Feature only products for which your app is currently developed.**

As it isn't for promotion an it's within the app does that mean I can't use them? I also noticed:

2.8 Rendering and illustration
Do not render in 3D or create any simulation of an Apple product. **Do not use illustration to depict an Apple product, except for instructional material.** If generic portable devices are illustrated, do not include details that are unique to Apple products, such as the round Home button or ring/silent and volume controls.

Well my tutorial is instructional, so I am wondering if I can use them...Any pointers on this  would be really appreciated! thanks

Comment: You are not marketing, so the page you linked (and any guidelines on it) are probably irrelevant. You probably can use the images, but you would want to contact Apple to be sure. We can't give you legal advice.

Answer (score 1):

If it's purely for instructional purposes, then you should be all set to go ahead and use the images. However, I don't work for Apple, so I don't know the exact details regarding their image use policy.